# Php error_log wont write errors to log

Tags: linux, php

I have moved my site to the production server (WHM) and my error logging in my php code is now not working.

I can see it is logging system php errors, but if i try and log anything myself from `error_log("my message",1)` it wont write the error. I can see that `error_log` returns `false` in my code.

I have no idea why the system can write php errors to file but i cannot from my code.

Any ideas would be super welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `error_log()` indicates message type. [As per the specification](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php), `1` means:

> message is sent by email to the address in the destination parameter. This is the only message type where the fourth parameter, extra_headers is used.

The destination parameter would be the third parameter that is not given in your `error_log()` call. I think what you want is using `0` or omitting the message type parameter, and letting it default to `0`